# Sinon stub - stubbing an axios api generated with swagger

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, sinon, stub

I have a file generated by swagger open api. I am writing some tests and using sinon stubs for the first time. I am wondering how can I stub an api call from a class:

```
export class Api<SecurityDataType extends unknown> extends HttpClient<SecurityDataType> {

     case = {
        /**
         * @description Create new case
         *
         * @tags case-controller
         * @name CreateCase
         * @request POST:/case
         * @secure
         */
        createCase: (data: CreateCaseRequest, params: RequestParams = {}) =>
            this.request<CreateCaseResponse, any>({
                path: `/case`,
                method: "POST",
                body: data,
                secure: true,
                type: ContentType.Json,
                ...params,
            }),

       findMetadataForCase: (caseNumber: string, params: RequestParams = {}) =>
            this.request<CaseDto, void>({
                path: `/case/${caseNumber}`,
                method: "GET",
                secure: true,
                ...params,
            }),
      }
}
```

I am instantiating this Api like this:

```
import { Api as CaseApi } from "../api/CaseApi";
export const CASE_API = useApi(new CaseApi({ baseURL: environment.url.case }), "case", "fss");
```

I have also made a file that deals with this api:

```
export const useApiData = () => {
    const [networkError, setNetworkError] = useState<string>(null);

    const fetchCase = async (caseNumber: string) => {
        const case = await CASE_API.case.findMetadataForSak(caseNumber);
        return case.data;
    };

    const getCaseAndRoles = (caseNumber: string) => {
        const { data: sak } = useQuery({
            queryKey: `case-${caseNumber}`,
            queryFn: () => fetchCase(caseNumber),
            staleTime: Infinity,
    });

        const { data: roles } = useQuery(
           "roles",
           ({ signal }) => fetchPersons(case, signal).then((persons) => mapPersonsToRoles(case, persons)),
           {
               staleTime: Infinity,
               enabled: !!case
            }
        );

    return { case: case, roles: roles };
};
    const api = {
        getCaseAndRoles,
    };

    return { api, networkError };
};
```

I would like to unit test a component that calls `getCaseAndRoles` from `useApiData` hook.

```
export const CasePage = () => {
    const { activeStep, setActiveStep, caseNumber } = useCase();
    const { api, networkError } = useApiData();
    const { case, roles } = api.getCaseAndRoles(caseNumber);

    return (...some jsx
```

I would like to test this component with fake data:

```
describe("CasePage", () => {
    it("should render", async () => {
        mockCase();
        render(<CasePage />);
        await waitFor(() => expect(document.querySelector("button")).not.to.be.null);
    });
});
```

But, I am not sure how to create a mock stub for it:

```
export function mockSak(sinonSandbox: SinonSandbox = 
 sinon.createSandbox()) {
    const caseApiMock = sinon.stub(useApiData()).returns({ getCaseAndRoles: () => {} });

    sinonSandbox.stub(caseApiMock, "getCaseAndRoles").callsFake(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(caseTestData);
    });

    return sinonSandbox;
}
```

But, that is not working, I get an error when running test:

```
    Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I have also tried this:

```
export function mockCase(sinonSandbox: SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox()) {
    sinonSandbox.stub(useApiData).callsFake(() => {
        return { api: { getCaseAndRoles: () => Promise.resolve(caseTestData) } };
    });

    return sinonSandbox;
}
```

But, then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: sinonSandbox.stub(...).callsFake is not a function
```

I have tried this as well:

```
export function mockSak(sinonSandbox: SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox()) {
    sinonSandbox.stub(CaseApi, "case").value({
        findMetadataForCase: () => Promise.resolve(caseTestData),
    });

    return sinonSandbox;
}
```

But, then I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property case
```

Which is weird, because if I do `CaseApi.property.case` I can see it has that property.

How can I stub this api call?

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Remove the unrelated code